# Ansible: Switching to su user and when running tivoli db2 command, gives command not found

Tags: linux, ansible, su, ibm-server, db2

when manually ran db2 command on the server works. But when executing using ansible which switches to the user but fails to run the db2 command. I am stuck on this issue for the whole day. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

task item:

```
- name: Connect to tsmdb1 database
  become: true
  become_user: user
  shell: 'db2 connect to tsmdb1'
  args:
    chdir: /opt/tivoli/tsm/tsmmp/cfg
  register:  Connect_tsmdb1
  ignore_errors: true
```

**Output:**

```
fatal: [user]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "db2 connect to tsmdb1",
    "delta": "0:00:00.142899",
    "end": "2019-05-27 17:00:57.885281",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "db2 connect to tsmdb1",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/opt/tivoli/tsm/tsmmp/cfg",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2019-05-27 17:00:57.742382",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: db2: command not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: db2: command not found"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"stderr": "/bin/sh: db2: command not found",
```

the db2 command is not found in the regular $PATH. Your user probably has something in one of the profile files that makes sure you can find the db2 executable.

You have two options:

If you just need the path and no other variables set find out where the executable is by logging on and running `type db2` Then use the full path in your ansible shell:

```
shell: '/path/to/db2 connect to tsmdb1'
```

Or you might need other environment variables in whatever file is providing the db2 info.
Find out which it is (suspects are /etc/profile , ~/.bashrc , ...) and source it:

```
shell: '. /home/user/.bashrc && db2 connect to tsmdb1'
```